# How to call a function and it opens in another window?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi i'm creating a python naughts and crosses game and i want the board format to open in another window when i call the function which show the board format. So in one window it will have the program asking where you want to go and when i want to show the board i want it to open up in a separate window?

```
def boardf():
    os.system("mode con cols=15 lines=7")
    print (" ")
    print ("    |   |    ")
    print (" ---+---+--- ")
    print ("    |   |    ")
    print (" ---+---+--- ")
    print ("    |   |    ")
```

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: what is the "window" the program should open in? Are the windows the Windows command prompt shell (`cmd.exe`)? Or is it a windowing graphical environment like Tkinter?

Comment: 1) Windows 2) cmd.exe

Comment: For the record, `os.system` opens in a new shell; as soon as it finishes, that shell disappears (so trying to configure it is pointless). If you want to modify the current shell or whatever (opening a separate shell, configuring properties, etc.), you're usually stuck using OS specific tools, e.g. on Windows, using `pywin32`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using IDLE, but this should be sufficient to get the ball rolling. IDLE is an IDE that's installed with Python when you download it on Windows. You can open it by pressing the Windows key and searching for IDLE.

The code is rudimentary, but it should give you a good idea of how to create a new window using the Tkinter library. I read that on Python `2.x`, you need to import Tkinter with a capital T, so if you're using `3.x`, you might need to change the import to a lowercase t.

```
import os, Tkinter as tk

def boardf():
    os.system("mode con cols=15 lines=7")
    print (" ")
    print ("    |   |    ")
    print (" ---+---+--- ")
    print ("    |   |    ")
    print (" ---+---+--- ")
    print ("    |   |    ") 

def play_x():
    print("implement x logic here")

def play_y():
    print("implement y logic here")

def create_window():
    root_window = tk.Tk()
    b_x = tk.Button(root_window, text="x", command=play_x)
    b_y = tk.Button(root_window, text="y", command=play_y)
    b_x.pack()
    b_y.pack()
    root_window.mainloop()

def main():
    boardf()
    create_window()

main()
```

[image]